# Put image at top in Beamer class

Tags: beamer

I am using the `Beamer` class with `columns` environment. I am able to start the text from top by using `\documentclass[t]{beamer}` but the image always appears at the center of the column which is giving a bad look.

**Problem:** How can i bring the image at the top?

[image]
**my code is following:**

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

    \begin{document}
        \section{Getjag}
        \subsection{Getjag}

    %slide - 1
            \begin{frame}
                \frametitle{External ports in Getjag}   
                    \input{slide_1}                                 
            \end{frame}
```

**The code for `\input{slide_1}` is following:**

```
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Best in class Manipulation title winner team used simulation for their tail operated robot.
    \item Simulation displays the exact orientation of flipers, manipulator arm etc. 
    \end{itemize}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
%\centering
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{simulation}
    \caption{Tail operated robot team.}
    \end{figure}
\end{columns}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `minipages` with `t`op alignment and `\linewidth` for the image width (as oposed to a fixed length):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{External ports in Getjag}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Best in class Manipulation title winner team used simulation for their tail operated robot.
    \item Simulation displays the exact orientation of flipers, manipulator arm etc. 
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{ctanlion}
  \caption{Tail operated robot team.}
  \end{figure}
\end{minipage}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the width for the `minipage`s according to your needs.

<sub>CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.</sub>

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain why the downvote?

Comment: Dear downvoter: hi. `:)` Can I talk to you for a moment? I heard you downvoted this answer. In TeX.sx, we save downvotes for very specific situations, and to be honest with you, this one here is not the case. If you think there's something terribly wrong with this answer, please, pretty please, let Gonzalo know - that way you allow him to improve the whole answer. It's a win/win situation. `:)` Now, if you just downvoted it for the sake of promoting other answers, I'm afraid you misunderstood the voting system as a whole. Note that you can keep the downvote, but at least tell us why. `:)`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion but then the column in which the text is present (left column) is touching the cloumn in which the image is present(right column). I mean the center space between text and image got removed. I used `\vspace{-1cm}`..and it is giving me the kind of desired results

Comment: @skm in my example code, change `\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}` to `\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}` or adjust the wifth for the first minipage also.

Comment: @skm please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be that your picture with a width of 5.5cm is larger than your column. Can you try with something smaller? e.g. `width = .9\textwidth`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item item1
                    \item item2
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=1.05\textwidth]{simulation}
                \caption{Tail operated robot team.}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item item1
                    \item item2
                \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{simulation}
                    \caption{Tail operated robot team.}
                \end{figure}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The float placement specifiers in beamer are superfluous.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for the hint. You are completely right, I removed them from the code